# faster approaches in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

i wrote this block of code to get tons of blast results but it seems little slow because i use two 'for' loops to iterate over two files.So i'm wondering if theres a faster,greedy way to narrow down the iteration.

Here's the code

```
for tf_line in SeqIO.parse('deneme2.txt','fasta'):
    tf_line.description=tf_line.description.split()
    tempfile=open('tempfile.txt','w')
    for cd_line in SeqIO.parse('Mus_musculus.GRCm38.74.cdna.all.fa','fasta'):
        if cd_line.id==tf_line.description[1]:
            tempfile.write('>'+cd_line.id+'\n'+
                str(cd_line.seq)[int(tf_line.description[2])-100:
                                 int(tf_line.description[3])+100])
            tempfile.close()
            os.system('makeblastdb -in tempfile.txt -dbtype nucl '
                      '-out tempfile.db -title \'tempfile\'')
            cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(query='SRR029153.fasta' ,
                                          db="tempfile.db",
                                          outfmt=7,
                                          out=(tf_line.description[0]+' '+
                                               tf_line.description[1]))
            stdout,stderr=cline()
```

'deneme.txt' is 30 Mb big and something like this:

> SRR029153.93098 ENSMUST00000103567 999 1147
>   TCAGGCCAAGTTTCTCTC
>
> SRR029153.83280 ENSMUST00000181483 151 425
>   CAGGTTGAC
>
> SRR029153.108993 ENSMUST00000184883 174 1415
>   TGGCACCTTTGC
>   .....

'Mus_musculus.GRCm38.74.cdna.all.fa' file is 170 Mb big and something like this:

> ENSMUST00000181483
>   ACACTGAAGAT.....
>
> ENSMUST00000184883
>   ATCTTTTTTCTTTCAGGG.....

'Mus_musculus.GRCm38.74.cdna.all.fa' file has some sequence id's(ENSMUST...).I must find the matches between 'deneme.txt' file and 'Mus_musculus.GRCm38.74.cdna.all.fa.

It should take 4-5 hours but with this code it takes at least 10 hours

Any help would be appreciated because i must get rid of brutal algorithms like this and be greedier.
Thanks

Comment: How big is the `Mus_musculus.GRCm38.74.cdna.all.fa`?  Seems like instead of reading that each time and looking for a match, you could cache the data into a hash structure (using the id for keys) before parsing `deneme2.txt`, and do a lookup against the `tf_line.description[1]`?

Comment: General advice: If you haven't profiled your script, please do so, so you know which commands use the most time. (Just run `python -m cProfile myscript.py`.)

Comment: Help others to help you. Describe the task in plain English (it might allow to use an algorithm with better time complexity): what is input? how large is it? What is the expected result? *Measure* time performance. Provide [standalone self-sufficient benchmark code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can try (it allows to test correctness and time performance). Set goal: how fast is fast enough.

Comment: It's 170 Mb big but i'm kinda beginner,its only been several months since i started learning python and i didn't use dictionaries that much so can you be more expositive please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is still producing the same blasts but should be much faster. Read the comments in the code to to some more optimizing:

```
tf_data = {key: (int(val1), int(val2)) for key, val1, val2 in
           (line.description.split() for line in
            SeqIO.parse('deneme2.txt','fasta'))}

for cd_line in SeqIO.parse('Mus_musculus.GRCm38.74.cdna.all.fa','fasta'):
    if cd_line.id in tf_data;
        tempfile=open('tempfile.txt','w')

        tf_val1, tf_va2 = tf_data[cd_line.id]

        #If it is likely that the same tf_data-record is used many times
        #move the math to the first line, if on the other hand it is
        #very likely that most records won't be used in tf_data then
        #move the int-casts back to the line below
        tempfile.write('>{0}\n{1}'.format(
            cd_line.id,
            str(cd_line.seq)[tf_val1 - 100: tf_val2 + 100]))

        tempfile.close()
        os.system('makeblastdb -in tempfile.txt -dbtype nucl '
                  '-out tempfile.db -title \'tempfile\'')
        cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(
            query='SRR029153.fasta',
            db="tempfile.db",
            outfmt=7,
            out=("{0} {1}".format(tf_val1, tf_val2)))

        #Since not using stderr and stdout don't assign variables
        cline()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Thats a good approach for dividing the problem and getting rid of all the unnecessary iterations.

Comment: You could probably speed up the first loop by parsing the file manually with regular expressions but I think most time is now spent on blasting. So to improve you would need multiprocessing. Anyways, if you're happy with the solution you should accept it ;)

Comment: Parsing isn't the problem here,its finding the proper match but using dictionaries will speed up the code.Multiproccessing is another thing :).Thanks again for your time.

Comment: What I meant is that `SeqIO.parse` is probably slower than a specific `re.search` but that what you gain will probably only be in the range of a minute tops which isn't worth it for a 4h run

Comment: and accepting you do by clicking the sign to the left of the zero at the top of my answer (if you think my answer is correct / good)